# Select Plugin Version for Intellij Idea IDE

Tags: intellij-idea

Seems the newest ruby plugin (5.4.0.20130410) has been broken/changed because jump to source (CTRL + click on method name) is not working.

Is there any possibility to select Plugin Version on installation, so I could revert to previous version?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to install specific Plugin Version is explained under following url.

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/RUBYDEV/Getting+latest+version